# How can I transform a string with form of a list into a tensor?

Tags: python, string, list, tensorflow, categorical-data

When I read a csv file with the next entrance
2,3,"['Action','Children']"
I want to read the third entrace as a tensor with a two strings but when I use

```
tf.decode_csv('2,3,"['Action','Children']" ',[0,0,""])
```

Current result is:

```
b"['Action','Children']"
```

How can I get as a result:

```
tf.string ["Action","Children"] shape=(1,)
```

I want to use this as a `cathegorical_features`.

Comment: you can use `tf.compat.as_str_any` to convert byte to string in tensorflow

Comment: The presence of "Action" and "children" suggests (at least) 2 features. Perhaps you could clarify if you are trying to map these out individually (so each record gets 2 new features, one for Action and one for Children) or if you are trying to map this as a "cross feature" - One new column but each possible combination of values is a distinct possible category for your categorical feature

Comment: @Stewart I want to transform the tensor `b"['Action','Children']"` into a tensor 
`[b'Action',b'Children']`, because I notice that the second one works well with the `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list()`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve in this way:

```
CSV_COLUMNS=["Int1","Int2","genre"]
DEFAULTS=[0,0,["Unknown"]]
columns = tf.decode_csv('2,3,"['Action','Children']" ', record_defaults=DEFAULTS)
features = dict(zip(CSV_COLUMNS, columns))
features["genre"]=tf.regex_replace(features["genre"],pattern="\[",rewrite="")
features["genre"]=tf.regex_replace(features["genre"],pattern="\]",rewrite="")
features["genre"]=tf.regex_replace(features["genre"],pattern="\'",rewrite="")           
features["genre"]=tf.strings.split(features["genre"],sep=",",result_type="RaggedTensor")
```